# Cannot turn off the AlwaysOn feature on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to turn off the AlwaysOn feature for my App Service, but after saving the change it reverts back to "On".

It's a Windows Service Plan currently on a B1 pricing tier. I'd like to scale down to either D1 or F1 pricing tier but those require the AlwaysOn feature to be turned off. When I try to scale down to either of those pricing tiers I get a notification:

"Cannot update the site '[my-site-name]' because it use AlwaysOn feature which is not allowed in the target compute mode"

So I then go to the apps Configuration > General Settings, turn off the AlwaysOn feature and save. When I refresh to check if the change saved the AlwaysOn feature is back to On.

Summary of steps I'm taking to turn off AlwaysOn feature:

1. From the App Service > Configuration > General Settings
2. Toggle "Always On" from "On" to "Off"
3. "Save" and "Continue"
4. I refresh and the AlwaysOn feature reverts to "On"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you hosting Azure Functions in your AppService plan? This might be a possible reason, though I have never heard of this behavior. Other than that, I would suggest you contact Azure Support.

Comment: I am not hosting any Azure Functions.  I'll take a closer look and then contact Azure Support.  Nevertheless thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What App Service Plan are you using?

By default, web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources. By enabling Always On you keep the app loaded all the time.

Just trying to understand and confirm, why are you attempting to disable?

Are you an admin, co-admin or contributor on the subscription?
Do you notice the activity success when you disable Always On?

[image: Activity log upon disabling Always-on config]

[image]

Kindly try these steps just to isolate the issue:

- Try this operation on a different browser and validate.
- If feasible restart the WebApp and then test.
- Scale-down App Service plan and then re-check.

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify my intents.  Also I've tried a different browser and have also restarted the app several times with same result.